# What happens, when the pump discharge velocity is faster than 3 m/s?

Tags: design, pumps

I am doing a gerotor pump application design.

I know the velocity of the suction port should be 1 ~ 2 m/s to avoid cavitation. Since I have enough space for suction port, it is not a problem.

Yet, the discharge port's diameter must be 16 pi because of the space and sealing problem. I read that discharge velocity should be 3 m/s, but I found the discharge velocity goes up to 4.5m/s when I calculated it with diameter 16.

What would happen if the discharge velocity is over 3 m/s?

Comment: The fluid comes out quicker ... friction losses increase, noise increase .

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. can I get formula for it?

Comment: What formulae have you found so far? What did you use to calculate the velocity?

Comment: I used 'V=1000*Q/60*AP(m/s)' from Nichols Portland, LLC Application data.